# Using Ajax to loop through nested Array to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

Good Morning, using ajax call I am trying to return the values of a nested json array, I was successful to pull the data except for the nested array  "booking_status". When I try loop through the 'booking_status', I git the value **[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]** . If I try to specify a value for example item.booking_status.status I get this **undefined**.

This is my nested array

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "item_name": "Misrry",
        "author": "Stephen King",
        
        "booking_status": [
            {
                "check_in": "2021-09-22T08:27:00+04:00",
                "check_out": "2021-09-23T08:27:00+04:00",
                "status": "Currently Booked"
            },
            {
                "check_in": "2021-09-25T08:37:00+04:00",
                "check_out": "2021-09-26T08:37:00+04:00",
                "status": "Currently Free"
            },
            {
                "check_in": "2021-09-27T08:37:00+04:00",
                "check_out": "2021-09-28T08:37:00+04:00",
                "status": "Currently Free"
            }
        ]

{
        "id": 2,
        "item_name": "Rose Red",
        "author": "Stephen King",
        
        "booking_status": [
            {
                "check_in": "2021-09-22T08:27:00+04:00",
                "check_out": "2021-09-23T08:27:00+04:00",
                "status": "Currently Booked"
            },
            {
                "check_in": "2021-09-25T08:37:00+04:00",
                "check_out": "2021-09-26T08:37:00+04:00",
                "status": "Currently Free"
            }
           
        ]
}
]
```

and this is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/', 
       
        
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var content = ''
                    data.forEach(item => {

                        content += "<tr><td>"
                            + item.item_name + "</td><td>"
                            + item.author + "</td><td>" + item.booking_status
                            + "</td></td></tr>"
    
                    })

                
                    $('#table_body').html(content);

                })

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `booking_status` is an array... How do you want to display that data in your table? You're going to have to get one element from the array, or iterate over it...

Comment: You're also iterating over `data` twice. (`for` loop and `data.forEach`) remove the `for` loop, it's redundant

Comment: 1) You don't need a second `$(document).ready` function. 2) You don't need a `forEach` inside that other loop. The first one will be able to access the data. 3) _But_ `booking_status` is an array so you _will_ to loop over that to access _that_ data depending on what you need your output to look like.

Comment: the json you have provided here have a error your first object is missing closing curly bracket and comma

Comment: The document is only ready once. This event happens only once per page load. In your code, for some reason you are adding many many listeners for this event that already happened (it already happened, because the whole code is already executed after `$(document).ready`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code.

- You're iterating over `data` twice. (`for` loop and `data.forEach`);
  Remove the for loop, it's redundant.
- `booking_status` is an array, so you're going to have to stringify it, or iterate over it somehow.
- You don't need to nest `$(document).ready`. The inner calls can be removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        var content = '';
        data.forEach(item => {
          content += "<tr><td>" +
            item.item_name + "</td><td>" +
            item.author + "</td><td>" + item.booking_status.map(s => s.status).join('<br/>') +
            "</td></td></tr>";
        });

        $('#table_body').html(content);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really helpful, I am very grateful for the explanation more than any thing. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. Quick question though, is there a way to return for example the status of the booking based on the current time? you now how there are multiple bookings for one item. Rather than returning all of them, I would like to return only one value based on the current time if it makes sense. So one status cell on the table based on the current time. What logic would achieve this?

Comment: Yea, that's possible, but you'd have to filter the `booking_status` array, whilst parsing the date strings to date objects. (`new Date('2021-09-27T08:37:00+04:00')`). Then you'll have to take care of the possibility that there's no results from that filter.

Comment: Do you mean using Array.prototype.filter()? can you please elaborate!

Comment: Do you mean something like this ---> let currentDate = new Date()
    const result = item.booking_status.map(s => s.status).join.filter(status = currentDate);
    console.log(result);  this code is absolute wrong, I never used this method so I need to see tutorials first to apply it correctly, but is this what you meant??

Comment: I suggest you look up some documentation on `filter` and `Date`, indeed. You'll need to `filter` the `booking_status` array, then get the first result from that, and get the `status` string from that result.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I think I have a rough idea of how to do it. I'll try hope it will work. I'll show my codes once done. Thank you Cerbrus.